# Magento filters SOAP v2 with Node JS / soap package

Tags: javascript, node.js, magento, soap

I am trying to use the filter for Magento SOAP v2 (Magento 1) but my code doesn't seem to work. I tried several ways of building to object with arrays but none of them seems to affect the returning results.

Can anybody explain me the right way to do that?

What I want to do is pull in all invoices but for example with a specific invoice ID or date.

Link to official Magento documentation:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrderInvoice/sales_order_invoice.list.html

This is my current code:

```
   const filter = {
        'complex_filter': [
                {
                    key: 'invoice_id',
                    value: {
                        key: 'eq',
                        value: '94'
                    } 
                }
            ]
        };


    client.salesOrderInvoiceList(res, filter, function(error, result) {
        console.log(result.result)
    });
```

In the above example I only tried to use the filter for the invoice ID but I also tried with the date but that didn't work out either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the easiest solution was to just map exactly to what the XML document would look like if this was done by PHP SoapClient.

```
const args = {
    sessionId: session_id,
    storeView: store_id,
    filters: {
        complex_filter: {
            complexObjectArray: {
                key: 'created_at',
                value: {
                    key: 'from',
                    value: '2017-01-01'
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

client.catalogProductList(args, (err, result) => { ... }
```